# Is putting content in the codebase or the database better for performance?

Tags: 7, theming, database, performance

I recently created a website footer using a block template. Some of the footer's content was entered through the block's wysiwyg (stored in the database), but other code-heavy elements were placed in the block template file (stored in code). I've noticed that the footer block loads slow at times. Other times, the content inserted through the wysiwyg loads a few seconds before the content that was inserted in the the block template.

I'm curious, is storing html content in the database better for performance than storing html content in template files?

EDIT: After I posted this, I also realized that the footer is being rendered with Blocks whereas the rest of the page is being render with Panels. I'm not sure if that would have any effects of its performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer is that the DB should be slower. In reality the only way to know for sure is to profile the PHP code and get a cache grind of it. One being rendered by panels and the other by core blocks is the main reason most likely in this case.